# Word Frequency Counter Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Struggling with this exercise which must use a dictionary and count the number of times each word appears in a number of user inputs. It works in a fashion, but does not atomise each word from each line of user input. So instead of counting an input of 'happy days' as 1 x happy and 1 x days, it gives me 1 x happy days. I have tried split() along with the lower() but this converts the input to a list and I am struggling with then pouring that list into a dictionary.

As you may have guessed, I'm a bit of a novice, so all help would be greatly appreciated!

```
occurrences = {}
while True:
    word = input('Enter line: ')
    word = word.lower() #this is also where I have tried a split()
    if word =='':
        break
occurrences[word]=occurrences.get(word,0)+1
for word in (occurrences):
    print(word, occurrences[word])
```

**EDIT**

Cheers for responses. This ended up being the final solution. They weren't worried about case and wanted the final results sorted().

```
occurrences = {}
while True:
    words = input('Enter line: ')
    if words =='':
        break
    for word in words.split(): 
        occurrences[word]=occurrences.get(word,0)+1
for word in sorted(occurrences):
    print(word, occurrences[word])
```

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and output of your code?

Comment: After you split() the input line, you should iterate through the newly-formed list, adding each individual word to your dictionary counter.

Comment: also, I'm not sure if its just part of your posting or your original code, but your code does not appear to have a chance to break out of the while loop, as the indentation is incorrect (here in the post)

Comment: @dm03514, counter is a good suggestion, but OP said the exercise requires dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is almost there, you just want to loop over the words when adding them to the dict

```
occurrences = {}
while True:
    words = input('Enter line: ')
    words = words.lower() #this is also where I have tried a split()
    if words =='':
        break
    for word in words.split(): 
        occurrences[word]=occurrences.get(word,0)+1
    for word in (occurrences):
        print(word, occurrences[word])
```

Answer (score 0):

This line does not get executed: occurrences[word]=occurrences.get(word,0)+1

Because if it enters the if, it goes to the break and never executes that line. To make it be outside of the if don't indent it.

In general, the indentation of the posted code is messed up, I guess it's not really like that in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want line by line stats or do you want overall stats ? I'm guessing you want line by line, but you can also get overall stats easily by uncommenting a few lines in the following code:

```
# occurrences = dict()  # create a dictionary here if yuo want to have incremental overall stats
while True:
    words = input('Enter line: ')
    if words =='':
        break
    word_list = words.lower().split()
    print word_list
    occurrences = dict()  # create a dict here if you want line by line stats
    for word in word_list:
        occurrences[word] = occurrences.get(word,0)+1

    ## use the lines bellow if you want line by line stats
    for k,v in occurrences.items():
        print k, " X ", v

## use the lines bellow if you want overall stats
# for k,v in occurrences.items():
    # print k, " X ", v
```